# How to display array of objects php in angular js table?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, function, response

I am getting started with Angular and PHP. I have a JSON array, this send the PHP file to AngularJS function through `$http` call, but i cant get JSON array values in function js.

the json result with console log is:

[image: ConsoleLog result]

php function:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
   $out[] = $row;  
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

js:

```
app.controller('controllerJs', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
$scope.clients = [];

$scope.All = function(){
   $http.get('/App/getAll.php')
           .then(function(data){
              $scope.clients = data;
           });
}

}]);
```

php table:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in clients">
      <td>{{item.nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{item.especialidad}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: `$scope.clients = data;` ==> `$scope.clients = data.data;`

Comment: _Small point_ `foreach ($result as $row) { $out[] = $row; } echo json_encode($out);` ___Why not just___ `json_encode($result);` ___and save all those wasted CPU cycles___

Answer (score 0):

You should access the **`data`** property of the response,

```
$scope.All = function(){
   $http.get('/App/getAll.php')
           .then(function(data){
       $scope.clients = data.data;
   });
}
```